# In a Visual C++ project, how do I give users redistributable .dll files?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm a new C++ / visual studio learner so sorry if I don't know something that might be obvious.

Alright so I understand that to get my programs to run on machines without VS I need to distribute the correct .dll files to them. Here are my questions:

1. How do I know what files to distribute? Once I know the files I need, where can I find them? I already have the .dll package microsoft provides installed but I don't know where to find it or the files in it.
2. How do I supply these files to the user? Can I just include the files with the installer and then on program start through code move the files to the correct spot? How do I do this? Is it possible to move the files to the correct location through the installer or do I have to do it when the program launches for the first time?

Thanks! Sorry if I left out information or if I formatted this question improperly.

Comment: CMake provides a module `InstallRequiredSystemLibraries` that handles these details.  (Not sure whether moving to CMake makes sense for the particular project, so not making this an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to statically link your application, then no C++ DLLs are needed.

Otherwise, Microsoft has "redistributable package" EXEs for each version of Visual Studio that you can include with the files that you provide to users.  Your installer then runs these as a sub-install.  (It does something like start another process that runs that package then waits for it to finish.)

Google visual studio redistributable.

Normally you would use a setup program / installer like InstallShield or WIX, and some of them already have built-in support for adding the redistributables for C++ and DirectX.